# Windows Media Encoder to record screen for WinRT

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, sharing

I used wmencoderor System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace to capture the screen by using C# in a desktop application. Now I need to capture the screen and share it among devices in JS WinRT.

**MY question is How to capture the screen and share it in JS metro app.**

shall I use something like System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace to Encodes a collection of Bitmap Frames objects to an image stream. ???

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to capture a screen shot in WinRT. You will have to do this via a non-windows runtime application.

Comment: No, you could have a server component that the winRT app interacts with. You will never be able to get anything like this into the windows store however.

Comment: and what about this app Remote Desktop
http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/remote-desktop/051f560e-5e9b-4dad-8b2e-fa5e0b05a480

Comment: That isn't capturing the screen, it's showing you the screen that someone else has captured (or drawing the screen)

Comment: thank you again ...So if I want to share the screen by any method How I should do this ?

Comment: what I want to do is to share the instructor screen to his students.

Comment: Does the instructor have to use a windows store app? If so you have limited options, but if you load all data and display all data in your app, then you could simple share this info with the connected clients.

Comment: the instructor use a JS metro application on his PC. So what's the best option I should use. thannk you again.